# WebSphere Debugger not stopping at breakpoints in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, websphere, rad

I have deployed my application on WAS 8 as debug.  The server status is [Debugging, Synchronized].  When I put breakpoints and start the application, it doesn't stop at the breakpoints.  I don't see the debugger thread start either.

I am using RAD 8.0.4 and JDK 1.6.0_31.  I have tried cleaning the project and re-deploying but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm working on Eclipse and WAS 8.5.5 and have the same problem. Did you solve yours?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working via a complete clean install of my app. Then removing it from the server via add remove. Clearing cache from the websphere/profiles/myprofile directory. and clearing all bits of my app from the profiles folder via a search for its containing file aka (myproject-folder). Then re-installed the app via add remove on the server and it worked for me.

Best guess I have is something was actually out of sync even though the server though everything was A okay.

Answer (score -1):

WebSphere is a PITA and seems to get out of state too easily.

I'd restart the server and perhaps do a clean on the server (right click on the server, click "Clean...".  If that doesn't work, you'll have to take a careful look at the location of your break points.  They might not be on code that's getting executed.  Place a break point further upstream if necessary, follow it down just to confirm the flow.

Comment: I cleaned the server, but still don't see the debugger thread start.